# Upload files to Google Drive programmatically

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

My requirement is to upload a single file which will be selected by the user during runtime to Google drive. I am getting email id and password from user. How to do it? If i any other requirement get from users? any feasible solution is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Google Drive SDK/API, it's fairly simple stuff if you read through the documentation,

https://developers.google.com/drive/

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads

There's a .NET API available for download, although it's in beta I've used it without problem.

https://developers.google.com/drive/downloads

Comment: Thanks but i have one doubt. I get email id and password from my user. google drive api ask client id and client secrect. How to get it those detials using email id and password

Answer (score 0):

DocumentsService myService = new DocumentsService("application name");
myService.setUserCredentials("email", "password");
DocumentEntry newEntrys = myService.UploadDocument("pdf path", @"upload file name");

But I have take exception 
Execution of request failed: https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full?convert=false